# Access Controller from other Controller in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a way to access the function from `FirstController` to `SecondController`? if there is, could please someone show me the way. 

`FirstController` :

```
class FirstController extends Controller
{
    public function actionDownload($fileName)
    {
        $path = 'templates/'.$fileName;
        if(file_exists($path)){
            return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);
        }
    }
}
```

`SecondController` :

```
class SecondController extends Controller
{
    public function actionView($id)
    {

        // i want to access function download() from the FirstController here

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your code thus

`FirstController`:

```
use app\models\Downloader;

class FirstController extends Controller
{
    public function actionDownload($fileName)
    {
        Downloader::download($filename);
    }
}
```

`SecondController`:

```
use app\models\Downloader;

class SecondController extends Controller
{
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $filename = "file"; // set this as you wish

        Downloader::download($filename);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
}
```

`Downloader`: in `@app/models`

```
namespace app\models;

class Downloader
{
    public static function download(string $filename)
    {
        $path = 'templates/'.$fileName;
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);
        }
    }
}
```